# Jmeter - ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: org for class

Tags: jmeter

I just upgraded to version 4.5.0 of WebDriver, using JMeter 5.5, and can't perform any actions.

Based on the official docs: `https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/`
should be using like:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium) but I faced exception.
```

Is there any way how to resolve this exception, so I can use it for sendKeys or click actions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using [`groovy`](https://groovy-lang.org/) as the language
2. `JavaImporter` object is specific for [JavaScript](https://p-bakker.github.io/rhino/tutorials/scripting_java/#javaimporter-constructor)

This mix of languages is not supported, you either need to switch to `javascript` in the "Language" dropdown or re-write your code in Groovy using [`import` statement](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) and replace `var` occurrences with `def`

Also according to [Top 15 UI Test Automation Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ui-test-automation)

> **NEVER** use Thread.sleep() unless there are specific test requirements

so consider migrating to [Explicit Wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) instead

Comment: Under current implementaion javaScript is not available to be selected. I only have: beanshell | java | groovy | bsh | jexl2 | jexl. IS there any way how to enable JS, or groovy is recommended?

Comment: 1. [Groovy is recommended](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) mainly because it [provides better performance than other scripting engines](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter). 2. JavaScript has been [removed in Java 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372). If you want JavaScript back you need to migrate to Java 14- or use [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/)

Comment: Is there any proper example you can share with me on how to use groovy code? Especially handling the driver. thanks

Answer (score 1):

thanks @ Dmitri T for your direction. Since javaScript is droppped after java15, here is some sample code that I found usefull using: `Jmeter5.5 + Java17 + selenium version 4.5.0 + groovy as language`

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get("http://gmail.com/");
JMeterVariables vars = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();

java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);

def userIdElement = WDS.browser.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']"));
userIdElement.sendKeys("gest@gmail.com");

java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);


WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Comment: NICE, this works and answered my question, after hours of searching